# What's this rod part?

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands

[image]

Any ideas? I can't find a part number anywhere.[image]

Comment: It's not LEGO, but a clone brand.

Comment: Are you sure? there were several of them and the plastic quality seems to match Lego. I have a pretty good knowledge of what is and isn't but the older stuff sometimes gets me which is where this was found.

Comment: if that bar is 3.18mm in size - then it is not LEGO. However there is a slim chance this is part of some disassembled/broken element. Could you take a picture with some other element of known dimensions, like brick or plate?

Comment: Added another picture. the tolerances seem very similar to a standard Lego rod. the hollow end can comfortably fit a rod as if some kind of extension, while the outside fits into a standard anti-stud or tube bottom. I thought maybe it could be similar to this old style propellor pin, or even some of the belville or Scala umbrella posts.

Comment: I've found it in mixtures before, and have always had to admit that it seems to be tantalizingly well-made non-Lego. I am fairly sure I never found it in a group of parts where everything *else* was Lego.

Comment: From the looks I do not recognize this items as any currently available LEGO element. You can confirm this my checking the hole end that fit the bar - for legit LEGO element you should find either LEGO logo there or "C" sign and Part ID.